# VBA: Copy row from SourceSheet and paste into DestSheet using dynamic rows

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to copy area from another workbook.

SOURCE: The area starts from J15 to last row of J column. I'm having trouble with the syntax.

DESTINATION: The area where the paste is the same area as in the Sourceworkbook, but K Column (K15 to last row of J column)

The problem is the with statement. I keep getting this error:
https://pasteboard.co/HsxMzPZ.jpg

Picture of the sourcesheet for clarification
https://pasteboard.co/Hs8gDsF.jpg

```
Public Sub Subledger_Makro()


Dim Subwb As Workbook
Dim Subsht As Worksheet
Dim Sourcewb As Workbook
Dim SourceSht As Worksheet



Set Subwb = ActiveWorkbook
Set Subsht = Subwb.Sheets("SAPBW_DOWNLOAD")

SourceFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Open yesterdays Subledger Report")

Set Sourcewb = Workbooks.Open(SourceFile)
Set SourceSht = Sourcewb.Sheets("SAPBW_DOWNLOAD")



'Copies the previous day Subledger (SourceSht) report J-Column to new the Subledgers (DestSht) K-column
' DestSheet is todays Subledger
' SourceSheet is the previous day Subledger


 With SourceSht
.Range(.Cells(15, "J"), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row, "J")).Copy Destination:=Subwb.Subsht.Range("K15")
End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False





End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
.Range(.Cells(15, "J"), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row, "J")).Copy Destination:=Subwb.Subsht.Range("K15")
```

With

```
.Range(.Cells(15, "J"), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row, "J")).Copy
    Subsht.Range("K15").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```